# How to substring the column name in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named 'comment1abc'

I am writing a piece of code where I want to see that if a column contains certain string 'abc'

```
df['col1'].str.contains('abc') == True
```

Now, instead of hard coding 'abc', I want to use a substring like operation on column 'comment1abc' (to be precise, **column name**, not the column values)so that I can get the 'abc' part out of it. For example below code does a similar job

```
x = 'comment1abc'
x[8:11]
```

But how do I implement that for a column name ? I tried below code but its not working.

```
for col in ['comment1abc']:
    df['col123'].str.contains('col.names[8:11]')
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Sample dataframe:

```
f = {'name': ['john', 'tom', None, 'rock', 'dick'], 'DoB': [None, '01/02/2012', '11/22/2014', '11/22/2014', '09/25/2016'], 'location': ['NY', 'NJ', 'PA', 'NY', None], 'code': ['abc1xtr', '778abc4', 'a2bcx98', None, 'ab786c3'], 'comment1abc': ['99', '99', '99', '99', '99'], 'comment2abc': ['99', '99', '99', '99', '99']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = f)
```

and sample code:

```
for col in ['comment1abc', 'comment2abc']:
    df1[col][df1['code'].str.contains('col.names[8:11]') == True] = '1'
```

Comment: i don't get what you're trying to do. So from your sample dataframe, what would you like to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer would be simple like this:

```
for col in ['comment1abc', 'comment2abc']:
    x = col[8:11]
    df1[col][df1['code'].str.contains('x') == True] = '1'
```

Trying to use a column name within .str.contains() wasn't a good idea. Better use a string.